# Does the series $\sum \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converge uniformly on $[0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Consider the following series for $x \in [0,1)$:
$$
\sum \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}
$$
I figured that it converges, by using the ratio test: 
$$
\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \frac{x^{n+1}}{1+x^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{1+x^{n}}{x^n} = \frac{x+x^{n+1}}{1+x^{n+1}} < \frac{1+x^{n+1}}{1+x^{n+1}} = 1.
$$
with $a_n = \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$. However, I would like to determine if this convergence is uniform on this interval. I know that for $a<1$ it is uniform on the interval $[0,a]$, since $g_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ is increasing on the interval, so we have for every $n$:
$$
|g_n(x)| \leq \frac{a^n}{1+a^n}
$$
and $\sum \frac{a^n}{1+a^n}$ converges, as just shown, so the convergence of $\sum g_k(x)$ is uniform by the Weierstrass M-test.

However, is it uniform on $[0,1)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not uniform.

Set $S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^k}{1+x^k}$.

Then, for $n>m$,
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1)}|S_n(x)-S_m(x)|\geq\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{1^k}{1+1^k}=\frac{n-m}{2}$$

Therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in[0,1)}|S_n(x)-S_m(x)|$$ is not finite, and so $S_n$ is not uniformly Cauchy, i.e the series does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering, how do you get the first inequality, the supremum is greater or equal to $\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1^k}{1+1^k}$?

Comment: @Sigurd In general, if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ (which is the case for $f=S_n-S_m$) then $sup_{x\in[0,1)} f(x)\geq f(1)$, as you could talk a sequence $x_n\in[0,1)$ which converges to $1$, and obtain $sup_{x\in[0,1)} f(x)\geq \lim f(x_n)=f(1)$.

Answer (score 4):

The convergence is not uniform. For $x_n = \sqrt[n+1]{1- \frac1n}$ we have:

$$
\sup_{x \in [0,1)} \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{1+x^k} - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{1+x^k}\right| = \sup_{x \in [0,1)} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{1+x^k}
\ge \frac{x_n^{n+1}}{1+x_n^{n+1}}
= \frac{1-\frac1n}{2-\frac1n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \frac12
$$

so it doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: How do you get the last inequality? I.e., you have defined $x_n = \sqrt[n]{1-1/n}$, now how do you get $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n^k}{1+x_n^k} \geq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n^n}{1+x_n^n}$$? (this needs a bit more detail)

Comment: @ClementC. You're right, it was wrong. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: You're welcome! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

In general, if $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on a set $E,$ then $\sup_E |f_n| \to 0.$ In our problem we have

$$\sup_{[0,1)} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \ge \sup_{[0,1)} \frac{x^n}{2} =  \frac{1}{2}.$$

Thus the series fails to converge uniformly.

Comment: How is x^n/(1+x^n) ≥ x^n/2

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal  Show that $u/(1+u)$ is increasing on $[0,1].$ Then let $u=x^n.$

Comment: Oh nvm, it directly follows since if 0≤x<1, then 0≤x^n<x<1, so 1/(1+x^n) > 1/2